# Checkpoint update issue in R

Tags: r, rstudio, checkpoint, microsoft-r

I ran the following line of code to update my checkpoint for R (ML server version)

`checkpoint("2019-12-30",checkpointLocation = tempdir()`

but I got the following error.

```
  |======================================================================================          |  89%Loading required package: emo
  |============================================================================================    |  95%Loading required package: emo
  |================================================================================================| 100%
- Discovered 307 packages
Unable to parse 19 files:
- R/R-3.5.1/library/MASS/scripts/ch16.R
- R/R-3.5.1/tests/utf8-regex.R
- R/win-library/3.4/checkpoint/examples/example_checkpoint.R
...
- R/win-library/3.5/timeSeries/extensionsTests/chicPlots.R
- R/win-library/3.5/timeSeries/extensionsTests/xtsWrappers.R

Error in gregexpr(makeSearchString(pkg), s) : 
  invalid regular expression 'package:{$|package:{
    {
        name
    }
}$|package:abind$|package:acepack$|package:AER$|package:agridat$|package:akima$|package:alr3$|package:ape$|
package:asd$|package:betareg$|package:BHH2$|package:Biobase$|package:boot$|package:brglm$|package:brglm.....|
package:expm$|package:expsmooth$|package:fastICA$|package:fields$|package:forcats$|package:foreach$|package:foreca
```

Comment: `getOption("repos")` gives:
`CRAN  "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01" `                                                                                                   
`CRANextra "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"`

Comment: So what code did you try to run. The code above only shows the result.

Comment: @NielsBerglund `checkpoint("2019-12-30",checkpointLocation = tempdir())`. I have updated the question also. Please help